# Problem displaying rotated text with Graphics32 in Delphi

Tags: delphi, graphics32

I have tried using the RenderText function to display rotated text on a TImage32 using the following code:

```
  Image.Bitmap.Font.Orientation := 200;
  Image.Bitmap.RenderText(100, 100, 'PRINT TEXT AT 20 DEGREE', 3, Color32(0, 0, 0, 255));
```

But the text is truncated at the top as if there was a clipping region where the text should normally be displayed if printed horizontally. Even the example program provided in the Gr32 library has this issue. Any idea how to display the text properly.

[image]

Comment: This just looks like the text has gone outside the bitmap. Why don't you output the text lower in the bitmap?

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: The text is cut out even if I print it at the bottom of the bitmap.  I am using X10 Seattle.

Comment: The same problem occurs also *without* `Graphics32`. Tested with a label of size h=230, w=500 and with `Font.Orientation = 200` and `Layout = tlBottom`. In Delphi XE7 the text is shown starting from left bottom but is *always* cut like in your example. In Delphi 10.4 it is initially shown starting from left bottom but cut as in your example. After a minimize - restore cycle it is however shown complete, but starting from the middle of the left side and going up to the right corner.